# Scala Traits - how to implement method

Tags: scala, interface, traits

How to properly extend and implement method `sendEmail` from `Person` trait (interface) inside `Employee` object bellow in order for main to execute:

```
trait Person {
  var name:String
  var gender:Char
  def sendEmail(subject:String, body:String)

}

object Employee extends Person {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
    sendEmail("a", "b")

    def sendEmail(subject:String, body:String): Unit = {
      println("subject" + body)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement all the abstract members of trait in the extending class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to implement all members and methods declared in trait `Person`.  Also, assuming you have multiple employees, `class` (or `case class`) might be more suitable than `object`:

```
trait Person {
  val name: String
  val gender: Char
  def sendEmail(subject: String, body: String): Unit
}

class Employee(val name: String, val gender: Char) extends Person {
  def sendEmail(subject: String, body: String): Unit =
    println(s"subject: $subject\n   body: $body")
}

object ListEmployees {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val emp1 = new Employee("Dave", 'M')
    val emp2 = new Employee("Jenn", 'F')

    emp1.sendEmail("yo", "yo yo yo")
    emp2.sendEmail("boo", "boo boo boo")
  }
}

ListEmployees.main(Array())
// subject: yo
//    body: yo yo yo
// subject: boo
//    body: boo boo boo
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `ListEmployees.main(Array())`? (it works without it)

Comment: It isn't part of the code, but a command for test running `ListEmployees.main()` on [Scala REPL](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/getting-started-scala-repl-command-line-shell-options).

Answer (score 0):

The method needs to be a member of the object rather than a function inside another function (main). Try:

```
object Employee extends Person {

  def sendEmail(subject:String, body:String): Unit = {
    println("subject" + body)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
    sendEmail("a", "b")
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a good catch but still did not work: `Error:(10, 8) object creation impossible, since:
it has 2 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from object Employee, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
  def gender_=(x$1: Char): Unit = ???
  def name_=(x$1: String): Unit = ???
object Employee extends Person {`

Comment: You also need to implement `name` and `gender`, something like `var name = "Joe"` and something similar for `gender` should suffice